# Story set on ocean planet, featuring floating islands

Tags: story-identification

I remember they imported dolphins but not sharks for some reason I don't remember. The story involved a spaceship crewman, I think he was in trouble for some reason. I think there were some planet citizens revolting against an interstellar government and the crewman ended up getting tied up with the rebels somehow.

I hope I'm not confusing two stories in my head, but I can't say for certain that I'm not.

Comment: Is it really a duplicate? It has the same answer, but no overlap on the plot points in the question. There isn't anything in the answer on the other question that references the OPs memory.

Comment: @Jontia Yes, it's a duplicate according to [our policy on story-ID duplicates](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/31394) - we close them if they have the same answer, regardless of whether or not the details in the question match.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks for the link. At least I can see what the thinking is now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dolphins are on the planet Maui-Covenant, the location of The Consul's Tale: "Remembering Siri" in Dan Simmons *Hyperion*.

> It was during the First Reunion, that time on the Archipelago, when Siri took me to talk to the dolphins.
>   [...]
>   The translator disk had twisted around so it trailed over Siri's shoulder. I reached to shut it off but paused as the answer to my question buzzed urgently in our ears.
>   *miss Shark/miss Shark/miss Shark/miss Shark/Shark/Shark/Shark*
>   I turned off the disk and shook my head. I did not understand.