# Name of a short story from Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was about a space sailor who would travel back and forth on 6 month trips that resulted in 11 years passing between each trip. He was assigned to a "primitive" planet to build a portal to allow instantaneous travel to it from the empire, so that it could be assimilated. He falls in love with a woman on the planet and learns years later that she is leading a revolution on the planet by those who do not want the empire to come, and eventually he sabotages the gate being constructed.

I read it 10 or 15 years ago? It was in an *Asimov's Science Fiction* that I found in an apartment that I rented.

Answer (score 16):

This is the "Remembering Siri" story from Dan Simmons' Hyperion cycle. It was previously asked about and answered here: [Story set on ocean planet, featuring floating islands](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65463/story-set-on-ocean-planet-featuring-floating-islands)

You seem to be looking for the short story version, which, per ISFDB, was published in the December 1983 issue of Asimov's magazine, and also independently collected in Simmons' anthology *Prayers to Broken Stones*. Many will recognize it from its inclusion in *Hyperion*. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayers_to_Broken_Stones#.22Remembering_Siri.22):

> Simmons used it as the seed for Hyperion (in which it appears nearly
> verbatim)

Here's the relevant quote from the story about the protagonist's sabotage of the portal:

> "So it is with great pleasure that I close this circuit, and welcome
> you, the colony of Maui-Covenant, into the community of the Hegemony
> of Man."
>
> The thin thread of the ceremonial com-laser pulses to the zenith.
> There is a spattering of applause and the band begins playing. I
> squint skyward just in time to see a new star being born. Part of me
> knows to the microsecond what has just occurred.
>
> For a few microseconds the farcaster had been functional. For a few
> microseconds time and space *had* ceased to be obstacles. Then the
> massive tidal pull of the artificial singularity triggered the
> thermite charge I had placed on the outer containment sphere. That
> tiny explosion had not been visible but a second later the expanding
> Schwarzchild radius is eating its shell, swallowing thirty-six
> thousand tons of fragile dodecahedron, and growing quickly to gobble
> several thousand kilometers of space around it. And *that* is visible
> -- magnificently visible -- as a miniature nova flares whitely in the clear blue sky.